# What is an inclusive way of asking for and storing a user's gender and sexual orientation?

Tags: user-profile

I need to ask for users' genders and sexual orientations, in a normalized way that allows for filtering users on both properties (so I can't just store user-provider strings). What's the most inclusive way to do this?

For genders, ISO_5218 recommends having the options: 0 (not known), 1 (male), 2 (female) and 9 (not applicable); but this groups a lot of people who identify in many distinct ways in the same bucket. For sexual orientations I haven't found a standard.

Right now I'm thinking of having a set of genders and a set of sexual orientations that users can pick from, as well as having the option to provide a custom string for both. But that's not great for filtering (custom strings would not fall into any filters), and I don't know what genders and sexual orientations to include in the list.

Are there any inclusive established practices for this?

Comment: Male/Female/Custom is what Facebook does...

Comment: Isn't this more of a [UX question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @noppa I'm not sure. Do you mean I should add a UX tag?

Comment: No, I mean this question probably shouldn't be in StackOverflow, which is for specific programming problems. You might get better answers in *ux.stackexchange.com*, for example, if your question fits their field of interest better.

Comment: @noppa ah gotcha thanks. Is it possible for me to move this question there, or should I just delete and copy/ paste the text?

Comment: I don't think you can *move* your own question without some more rep, so deleting & copy pasting is probably the way to go here.